# Prestashop combination generator not working when using lots of options

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop

When using prestashop 1.5.6 and trying to generate product combinations using the combinations generator, it works for say 40 colours and 5 sizes, but when trying to do more than that (Which we need to) it just doesnt do anything.

I've made a video; http://www.fastswf.com/SO3wm9g

Has anyone encountered this issue or know the fix?

Answer (score 0):

did you check out the PrestaShop Bugtracker. There are several entries that could match your Problem.

Look at http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-4493?jql=text%20~%20%22combinations%22 for example.

Kind regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because current combinations generator requires lots of server resources. Most of servers cannot handle huge number of attributes and throw 500 error.

I have the same issue on one of my projects and currently working on a new module that will handle creating thousands of combinations. Module will be available for sale in about a week.

If you don't want to buy it, here is general idea of how it works: it doesn't affect any core. It just creates new combinations in chunks via ajax. So, every 5-3 seconds a new request is sent to server and 50-100 new combinations are added. This method requires more time to wait, but at least combinations are created without errors.